# http.get() returns "422 Unprocessable Entity"

Tags: http, go, http-get

I have written a go programme to query issues in github repository "golang:go".
The http.Get() responds with status  "200 OK".
I then query for issues created in last 3 months and the http.Get() returns "422 Unprocessable Entity". Below is the programme

```
import(
        "fmt"
        "time"
        "net/http"
        "net/url"
        )

func main() {
        var ret error
        var str string 

        q:=url.QueryEscape("repo:golang/go")
        fmt.Println("q:", q)
        urlStr := "https://api.github.com/search/issues" +"?q=" + q 
        fmt.Println("urlStr:", urlStr)
        resp, ret:= http.Get(urlStr)
        fmt.Println("ret :", ret, "resp.status :", resp.Status)

        timeStr := "created:"
        to := time.Now()
        from := to.AddDate(0, -3, 0)

        str = to.Format("2006-01-02")
        timeStr = timeStr + str + ".."
        fmt.Printf("time1 : %s\n", timeStr)

        str = from.Format("2006-01-02")
        timeStr = timeStr + str 
        fmt.Printf("time2 : %s\n", timeStr)

        q=url.QueryEscape("repo:golang/go" + timeStr)
        fmt.Println("q:", q)
        urlStr = "https://api.github.com/search/issues" +"?q=" + q 
        fmt.Println("urlStr:", urlStr)
        resp, ret = http.Get(urlStr)
        fmt.Println("ret :", ret, "resp.status :", resp.Status) 
}
```

I used [this](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues) to form the query.

I am new to web programming and not able to understand where I went wrong in forming the second query.

Comment: thanks for bringing this API to my attention :)

Comment: your code works good but you just write `resp.Status` but there is nothing like `Status` in response body, that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: I think `q=url.QueryEscape("repo:golang/go" + timeStr)` this statement escapes the 2nd url wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two things that worked for me

1) reverse the "from" and "to" in your timeStr

2) don't use QueryEscape on the timeStr, just add it in like this

```
   urlStr = "https://api.github.com/search/issues" + "?q=repo:golang/go+" + timeStr
```

Don't use an ampersand (I originally answered with this) use a plus sign or space.  See https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues-and-pull-requests/#search-by-when-an-issue-or-pull-request-was-created-or-last-updated for the syntax

update: on further consideration the QueryEscape is a good idea!  It seems coincidentally to "just work"

Comment: I also reduced the time search range to 3 days instead of 3 months, it's quicker to test

Comment: `&` sets the `timeStr` as a separate query parameter and not as part of `q`, use `+` to concatenate the qualifiers.

Comment: mkopriva, that's a pretty weird API as + is usually a space!  I tried it with ampsand and it seemed (to me) to work correctly.  Will investigate further, thanks

Comment: Yes `+` is space and it's probably wiser to use that instead of the plus sign, nevertheless it should work with that the plus as well. At least it does for me.

Comment: I think the plus sign is quite nice in this context, meaning as an AND for the terms.  The reason the ampsand appears to work is that many of the results are as expected.  You are right of course, the space or plus is the correct symbol

Comment: @Vorsprung thanks for your suggestion, It worked. I tried both url formats one which you suggested & the other with url.QueryEscape and both worked. but final url string in both are different. without QueryEscape its: "https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:golang/go+created:2018-08-30..2018-11-30" and with queryescape its " https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo%3Agolang%2Fgo+is%3Aopen+created%3A2018-08-30..2018-11-30". I think one with QueryEscape is better as it does encoding internally than without QueryEscape where it is upto developer to do the right encoding. Please clarify.

Comment: ok so thinking about it and looking at the Go source for net/http, the get parameter (after the ?) is not automatically encoded .  The reason it works in both cases is probably because the http server you are contacting is able to cope with non compliant requests.  For future reference it is better to encode parameters of this type with url.QueryEscape

Answer (score 0):

I used like the following and it works for me if i don't escape the 2nd url:

```
package main
import(
        "fmt"
        "time"
        "net/http"
        "net/url"
        )

func main() {
        var ret error
        var str string 

        q:=url.QueryEscape("repo:golang/go")
        fmt.Println("q:", q)
        urlStr := "https://api.github.com/search/issues" +"?q=" + q 
        fmt.Println("urlStr:", urlStr)
        resp, ret:= http.Get(urlStr)
        fmt.Println("ret :", ret, "resp.status :", resp.Status)

        timeStr := "created:"
        to := time.Now()
        from := to.AddDate(0, -3, 0)

        str = to.Format("2006-01-02")
        timeStr = timeStr + str + ".."
        fmt.Printf("time1 : %s\n", timeStr)

        str = from.Format("2006-01-02")
        timeStr = timeStr + str 
        fmt.Printf("time2 : %s\n", timeStr)

        urlStr = "https://api.github.com/search/issues" +"?q=" + "repo:golang/go&created:2018-11-29..2018-08-29"
        fmt.Println("urlStr:", urlStr)
        resp, ret = http.Get(urlStr)
        fmt.Println("ret :", ret, "resp.status :", resp.Status) 
}
```

And the output is:

```
q: repo%3Agolang%2Fgo
urlStr: https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo%3Agolang%2Fgo
ret : <nil> resp.status : 200 OK
time1 : created:2018-11-29..
time2 : created:2018-11-29..2018-08-29
urlStr: https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:golang/go&created:2018-11-29..2018-08-29
ret : <nil> resp.status : 200 OK
```

Answer (score -1):

Many APIs including the one from [github](https://developer.github.com/v3/#client-errors) return the `422` status code when the client sends invalid input. In your code the bad input is generated by the line that concatenates the two qualifiers without a "separator".

So this `"repo:golang/go" + timeStr` will result in the `q` value containing a single "merged" qualifier that looks something like this:

```
"repo:golang/gocreated:2018-1...
```

To fix your code you just need to add a space between the two qualifiers and your query should work.

```
q=url.QueryEscape("repo:golang/go " + timeStr)
```